# asp.net mvc regular expression enter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]*$ for textarea
```

I want to make available the enter as well in the following regular expression. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to allow newline characters? That would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. \r\n]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use declarative attributes to accomplish this.

Here's a [post](http://creatingcode.com/2010/10/validating-input-with-asp-net-mvc-2/) to get you started.

Using your provided regular expression, you could do the following in your `model` code to make a field both required and validated against a specified criteria.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid text")]
public string MyTextBox { get; set; }
```

If you are interested in learning more about attributes (not necessarily with respect to ASP .NET MVC) you can check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(v=VS.100).aspx) for further reading.